# Can I change custom dynamic properties from a stylesheet (qss)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qframe

I have a custom `QFrame`like this

```
//! Widget which displays a audio level meter, indicating the
//! level and peak levels of the window of audio samples most recently analyzed
class BLACKGUI_EXPORT CLevelMeter : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor lowColor  READ getLowColor  WRITE setLowColor)
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor highColor READ getHighColor WRITE setHighColor)
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor peakColor READ getPeakColor WRITE setPeakColor)
```

I want to set those colors in an `qss` stylesheet like this

```
BlackGui--CLevelMeter {
  lowColor: blue;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
```

This does NOT work, any chance to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#setting-qobject-properties) points out:

> ### Setting QObject Properties
>
> From 4.3 and above, any designable
>   [Q_PROPERTY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_PROPERTY) can be set using the `qproperty-<property name>` syntax.
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> MyLabel { qproperty-pixmap: url(pixmap.png); }
> MyGroupBox { qproperty-titleColor: rgb(100, 200, 100); }
> QPushButton { qproperty-iconSize: 20px 20px; }
> ```
>
> If the property references an enum declared with Q_ENUMS, you should
>   reference its constants by name, i.e., not their numeric value.

You must use `qproperty-lowColor`.